# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I got this kind of error while I am running application on android device.Even I tried to uninstall by configuring the setting in general tab under edit configuration. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.But this was working on emulator.Event the package name is also in small letters.But still don't know the issue.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.arunmannuru.arun">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

        <!-- <uses-feature -->
        <!-- android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" -->
        <!-- android:required="true" /> -->
        <!-- <uses-feature -->
        <!-- android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" -->
        <!-- android:required="false" /> -->
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".ResponseActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".PromotionsFeedActivity" />
            <activity
                android:name=".Main2Activity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
            <activity android:name=".AddNewEvent" />
            <activity android:name=".Detail_PromotionFeed" />
            <activity android:name=".Profile" />
            <activity android:name=".Settings" />
            <activity android:name=".Search" />
            <activity android:name=".SearchFeedActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".CalendarActivity" />
            <activity android:name="Community.CommunityActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".ConnectBusinessActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".DialogClass" />
            <activity android:name=".BusinessProfile" />
            <activity android:name=".EventPost" />
            <activity android:name=".MediaActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".AddBusinessProfileActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".UserFeedBackActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".ContactUsActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".FaqActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".PrivacyPolicyActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".TermsServices" />
            <activity android:name=".RsvpPopUp" />
            <!--
                 The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
                 (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
                 Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
                 You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
                 sign the APK for publishing.
                 You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

            <activity
                android:name=".map_search"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_map_search" />
            <activity android:name=".Webview"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Android Studio->Analyze->Inspect code and check at bottom. is there any error or not?if there is error, please fix it. This operation will check whole your code

Comment: I found few errors.I resolved those errors.But still getting same error. @Rajesh Nasit

Comment: then do File->Invalidate Cashe/Restart and build->clean and Build->Rebuild project

Comment: Nope still same issue.. Did whole steps. @Rajesh Nasit

Comment: android:name=".map_search"  here dont use underscore use like .MapSearch if it works let me know